# Sitemap.xml file in Django + Gunicorn + Nginx web

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, sitemap.xml

I am deploying a Django project with Gunicorn + Nginx. I create a sitemap.xml file with the [sitemap framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/sitemaps/). I use a 127.0.0.1:8001 proxy so when i access to example.com/sitemap.xml the result is similar to this:

```
<url>
<loc>
http://127.0.0.1:8001/pages/item_1
</loc>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

When i add sitemap.xml to the Google index in Google Webmaster Tools, Google does not allow the sitemap.xml because the domain in location tag is 127.0.0.1:8001 and not my domain.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I am understanding your question right, you are asking why google is giving you an error accessing 127.0.0.1:8001

127.0.0.1 usually directs to localhost

and I'm pretty sure google won't be able to access that

what you will need is a domain name, or at least your server IP address

once you have those do the following:

make a file called generate_sitemaps.py

```
from foo.models import Foo
from django.contrib import site maps

class FooSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    changefreq = "hourly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Foo.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.updated


# make sure this is at the bottom of your generate_sitemap.py file
sitemaps = {
    'foo': FooSitemap,
}
```

in your urls.py file
    from generate_sitemap import site maps

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'site maps': sitemaps})
```

)

in foo/models.py you are going to need a get_absolute_url method to return  automatically for each entry

```
Class Foo(models.Model)
    ....
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('some_url', args=[self.id])
```

In your settings file:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    )
```

if you need more information about setting up sites and domains in django use checkout the [Django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand perfectly why Google does not allow upload the sitemap with 127.0.0.1 domain. My question: Is possible to substitute this:

<url>
<loc>
127.0.0.1:8000/pages/item1
</loc>
...
with this:

 <url>
 <loc>
 mydomain.com/pages/item1
 </loc>
 ...
I follow the instructions of Django Sitemap Framework and the absolute url returned starts with 127.0.0.1 domain and not mydomain.com (because i am using a proxy, i guess)

I edit the sitemap.xml and upload it as static file, but that it is only a temporary solution.

Comment: I think you need to enable the sites framework to enable site maps to return the correct domain 

in your settings file:
    SITE_ID = 1

then go into django admin and enter the domain (in the django_sites table). The url can be hard to find, probably something like:
http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/sites/site/1

also i updated the code above to ensure 'django.contrib.sitemaps', is in INSTALLED_APPS though you should have that already